# Code for capturing QR Code doesn't seem working well in Xcode8 and Swift3

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, swift3, ios10

I'm trying to capture QR code using `AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate` in Swift3 and iOS 10 beta device.

But `captureOutput` function is not called when QR code is actually captured by device's camera.

Does anyone have a solution for this? If so, please let me know how to fix and work properly.

Thanks,

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let mySession: AVCaptureSession! = AVCaptureSession()
    let devices = AVCaptureDevice.devices()
    var myDevice: AVCaptureDevice!

    for device in devices! {
      if((device as AnyObject).position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.back){
        myDevice = device as! AVCaptureDevice
      }
    }

    let myVideoInput = try! AVCaptureDeviceInput.init(device: myDevice)

    if mySession.canAddInput(myVideoInput) {
      mySession.addInput(myVideoInput)
    }

    let myMetadataOutput: AVCaptureMetadataOutput! = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()

    if mySession.canAddOutput(myMetadataOutput) {
      mySession.addOutput(myMetadataOutput)
      myMetadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
      myMetadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = [AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode]
    }

    let myVideoLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.init(session: mySession)
    myVideoLayer?.frame = self.view.bounds
    myVideoLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(myVideoLayer!)

    mySession.startRunning()
  }


  // MARK: - AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate

  // This function is not called despite capturing QR code  
  func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [AnyObject]!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
    if metadataObjects.count > 0 {
      let qrData: AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject  = metadataObjects[0] as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject
      print("\(qrData.type)")
      print("\(qrData.stringValue)")

    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The method header to implement `AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate` in Swift 3 has become like this:

```
func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!,
                   didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [Any]!,
                   from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
```

`[AnyObject]` -> `[Any]`, I haven't checked other parts of your code, but at least, you need to fix this.

Comment: Thanks for your quick mention. I fixed the point and it works! I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Good to know. I think Swift development is being handicapped by the number of changes in things like method headers between major versions

Answer (score 3):

The delegate method in Swift 4

```
func metadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

**SWIFT 3:** In my case this code solve the problem:

**Old INCORRECT CODE**

```
private func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [AnyObject]!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
    for item in metadataObjects {
        if let metadataObject = item as? AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject {
            if metadataObject.type == AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode {
                print("QR Code: \(metadataObject.stringValue)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**CORRECT ANSWER**

```
func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!,
                   didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [Any]!,
                   from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
    for item in metadataObjects {
        if let metadataObject = item as? AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject {
            if metadataObject.type == AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode {
                print("QR Code: \(metadataObject.stringValue)")
            }
        }
    }

}
```